# displaying text box dynamically jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie to jQuery and I would like to display a text box below if the user selects "Other". How will I select the individual item in the radio box?

Also, when the user un-clicks the OTHER button then the textbox should be removed.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("$select-car").click(function() {

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="select-car">
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="Toyota">GM<br>
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="Honda">Ford<br>
            <input type="radio" name="car" value="Other" onlick>Other<br>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: means you want to show/hide textbox on check/uncheck event of radio button ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#select-car input[type='radio'][name='car']").change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'Other') {
        //show textbox $('#txt').show();
    }
    else{
        //hide textbox $('#txt').hide();
    }
});
```

---

References

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

[this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

ok than add textbox below your html like this :

```
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext"/>
```

write jQuery like this

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $("#mytext").show();
    } else {
        $("#mytext").hide();
    }
});
```